# How to create a Shared Leave Calendar to view leave availability

Tags: excel, calendar, outlook, shared

I wanted to get some advice on how to create a shared leave calendar for my workplace to try and make it easier to book leave.

At present, unfortunately we don't have a facility where we can view what leave availability there is and are going back and forth with rejecting leave due to staff not being able to see what they can book.

I was looking to create a calendar of some sort whether this is in Outlook, Excel, Access, I am not fussed but something that can be shared and also giving the users more coverage of availability.

Any advice on a solution or workaround would really be useful as im not sure how to start this off.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have access to Google Docs in your office? If yes, everyone
   can have a view access of a common leave calendar (which can be an
   excel file) and the supervisor can have write access so that only he
   can make changes.
2. If you don't have access to google docs, the supervisor can create a    2nd calendar specifically for leaves) and share it with
   the team so    that team members can have a view access. You can find more
   details on creating a new calendar here: [https://faqs.aber.ac.uk/146][1]

Comment: Thanks guys, i will have a look at your suggestions and see how i get on.

Answer (score 0):

Google calendars can be shared across multiple accounts - you can view other people's calendars but not edit the information on them depending on permissions. So the leave calendar would be attached to the manager's account and they would need to approve changes but everyone could view. If someone wants to request leave they can add it as an event to their own calendar and 'Invite' the manager to the event. The manager can then accept the invite and add it to their own calendar which everyone would see.